# Jenkins Pipeline: How to access pipeline parameters and insert them into batch file argument

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use the parameterized build and I am getting lost in some sources right now. I thought it would be possible to access the build paramters with a "params.myParameter" call. Or a ${env.myParamter} but neither appear to be working. This does not cause syntax errors currently, but the parameter is being read as "" for the if statement and the param access is being used as a string for the batch call.

What I have is the following:

```
pipeline {
agent { 
    node {
        label 'dummy_label' 
    }
}
options {
    skipDefaultCheckout true
}
stages {
    stage('Setup') {
        steps {
            // For debug purposes, state which user we are running as
            bat 'whoami'

            // Now do the checkout
            timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                retry(10) {
                    // Sometimes this fails because Integrity is terrible.
                    checkout scm
                    sleep 5

                    // Check to see if "VerifyCheckout.bat" exists. Sometimes Integrity doesn't resync the files... just the folders. Again, Integrity is terrible.
                    bat ".\\HWIOAPPL\\Test\\Jenkins_scripts\\VerifyCheckout.bat"
                    
                }
            }
            dir("${env.PROJECT_ROOT}\\HWIOAPPL\\Test\\Jenkins_scripts") {
                bat ".\\QAC_CLI_Setup.bat"
                script{
                    if(params.Release_Tag != "mainline"){
                        bat ".\\ZIP_Software.bat 'params.Release_Tag'.zip"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } //More stages and stuff after this
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify your parameters in a `parameters` block at the top of the file - between the `options` and `stages` block should do (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters).

ex.

```
parameters {
     string(name: 'Release_Tag', defaultValue: '1.0', description: 'Version of the Release')
}
```